# Python - Using method in return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I've been doing some programming exercises and noticed some weird thing.
Code below is trying to use the artist name and the sales in a tuple and create two lists, artists and sales, and have the items in the list sorted in order. (Alphabetically and Large to Small)

```
def sort_artists(artist_list):

    artists = []
    sales = []

    for artist_tuple in artist_list:

        artists.append(artist_tuple[0])
        sales.append(artist_tuple[1])

    return (artists.sort(), sales.sort(reverse = True))

artists = [("The Beatles", 270.8), ("Elvis Presley", 211.5), ("Michael Jackson", 183.9)]
print(sort_artists(artists))
```

When I use the sort() method in the return statement, the outcome is

```
(None, None)
```

However, if I say

```
artist.sort()
sales.sort(reverse = True)

return (artist, sales)
```

Then it gives me the desired output..

I thought Python solves the innermost part first so I'm really not as to why it returns None for the case above.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `list.sort` will returns None. It does an `inplace` sort.

Comment: The `sort()` method modifies the list in place, and returns `None`. Use `sorted()` if you want to return a new, sorted list.